# How to do bitmasking for unsigned long int?

Tags: c++

I am working on branch predicter implementation in that I need to create a Branch history register (BHR) which stores `1111` into the first 4 bits of an `unsigned int`, after every prediction. We will get output from Finite-state machine and that is updated into the BHR using left-shift. Can you explain for me how to do that?

Here's what I've tried:

```cpp
struct BHR
{
    long int BHR_index;
    unsigned input = 0b1111u, n_bits = 4u, *bits =new unsigned[n_bits], bit = 0;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    long int table_size = 1227;
    BHR *table = new BHR[table_size];
    for(int  k = 0;k<=table_size;k++)
    {
        for(table->bit = 0; table ->bit < table ->n_bits; ++table->bit)
            table[k].bits[table -> bit] = (table -> input >> table ->bit)&1;
    }
    free(table->bits);
}
```

I did bit masking like this but I am getting thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) error in Xcode. Can anyone please help me.

Comment: post an example of what you need.... input -> output....

Comment: Use the & operator. For example:
a = b&0xf

Comment: What are starting bits? Most significant bits (MSB) or least significant bits (LSB)?

Comment: [Bitwise operations in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C)

Comment: Your question is very unclear, meybe something like `long int x = y & 0xf`??

Comment: I've now voted to reopen this question -  but I can't guarantee that 4 others will support that! However, in the meantime (I can post as an answer if/when it's reopened): You are accessing `table` in the wrong way! You should always use code like `table[k].bit = 0` in place of `table->bit = 0` (in many places) … and ***don't use `free` for stuff you made with `new`*** - use `delete[]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If by "starting 4 bits" you mean the **low** (least significant) 4 bits, then this mask will clear all others, leaving those 4 bits intact:

```cpp
unsigned long int someValue = 12345;
unsigned long int low4bits = someValue & 0xF;
```

This AND mask (`&` operator) works by clearing all bits in the destination that aren't set in ***both*** operands. So, as the value of `0xF` in binary is `...0001111`, all other bits will be cleared.

If you want the **high** (most significant) 4 bits, then you need to know the size of `unsigned long int` (although see below). If (as is common) this is 32-bits, then the mask you need will be as follows:

```cpp
unsigned long int someValue = 12345;
unsigned long int high4bits = someValue & 0xF0000000;
```

Feel free to ask for further explanation and/or clarification.

EDIT:
Actually, there is a way to get the mask for the high 4 bits of an `unsigned long int` even if you don't know its actual size, but it maybe a bit confusing. The code below is not the most 'efficient' way, perhaps; rather, it is designed to illustrate the process:

```cpp
unsigned long int zeroValue = 0; // All bits are clear.
unsigned long int notZero = ~zeroValue; // ~ inverts all bits, so now all set
unsigned long int top4Clear = notZero >> 4; // shift set bits by 4, and zero-pad top 4
unsigned long int top4Mask = ~top4Clear; // Again, the ~ operator inverts all bits
```

With this `top4Mask` value, we can now clear all but the high (most significant) bits:

```cpp
unsigned long int someValue = 12345;
unsigned long int high4bits = someValue & top4Mask;
```

Comment: can you please explain for the following example: I need to store 1111 into the first 4 bits of unsigned long int and i also need to do the left shift after every iteration.

Comment: @tejamandadapu Maybe you should ask a separate question, and make sure it's a lot clearer exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am working on branch predicter implementation in that I need to create  Branch history register(BHR) which stores 1111 into  the first 4 bits of unsigned int, after every prediction, we will get output from Finite-state machine and that is updated into the BHR using left-shift can you explain for me how to do that

Comment: @tejamandadapu There will be many folks here on SO (myself included) that could give you a good answer to the problem, if we new more details. Like how many bits you want to left shift by (I would guess by 4, then put the new 1111 into the 'cleared' low 4 bits). But, like I said, post this as a **new question**, explaining what you want and, ***importantly***, showing some attempt to code it yourself. Don't worry if your code is wrong - we can fix things.

Comment: @tejamandadapu Consider putting the code from your last comment, along with the explanation in your previous comment, into *this* question (use the "Edit" link). That way, it may well be reopened and attract more (even better) answers. Ping me if/when you do this, and I'll (probably) give it a reopen vote.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use bit-fields that do the bit masking for you:

```
struct ulong4b {
    unsigned long value : 4;
};

int main() {
    ulong4b a;
    a.value = 1; // Stores the lower 4 bits only.
    unsigned long value = a.value; // Reads the lower 4 bits only.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this macro will help you if you want to extract bits from a number :

```
#define GET_BITS(number, offbits, nbits) (((number) >> (offbits)) & ((1 << (nbits)) - 1))

int x = 12345;
int last4bits = GET_BITS(x, 0, 4); // last4bits = x & 0x0000000F;
int first4bits = GET_BITS(x, 32 - 4, 4); // first4bits = x & 0xF0000000;
```